# Safari and App Store missing after iOS7 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ios

I upgraded iTunes on my PC, backed up my iPhone and then upgraded my 4S to iOS7. Now I am missing the icons for Safari and App Store. Any tips on how to recover them?

Answer (score 1):

One sentence answer: **you accidentally turned on Restrictions.** *(Settings>General>Restrictions)*

Just slide the switches next to Safari and App Store. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Siri to open those apps.

If they are missing, you might need to erase and test before you load your backup. If they are not in their expected location, you could reset the home screen layout.

Comment: I got it all back- accidently turned on restrictions...

Comment: @MrEd Woah - that's a different answer than I expected. Want to edit it into mine or self-answer this? The second option might be better but it's totally your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and when I turned off all restrictions in Settings/General on my iPhone, the Safari app reappeared.  No need to re-install software or anything else...

Answer (score -1):

turned off restrictions safari app restored